# Generate PHP combinations for size and color

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to generate combinations of sizes with colors in php. Basically here is what I have:

- Sizes: Small, Medium, Large
- Size Count: 3
- Colors: Blue, Red, White
- Color Count: 3

The sizes and colors may vary depending on each product. The outcome I would like to have is like this:

> Small Blue
>   Small Red
>   Small White
>   Medium Blue
>   Medium Red
>   Medium White
>   Large Blue
>   Large Red
>   Large White

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$sizes = array('Small', 'Medium', 'Large');
$colors = array('Blue', 'Red', 'White');

foreach($sizes as $size) {
    foreach($colors as $color) {
        echo $size." ".$color;
    }
}
```

That will give the output you described.